# Can i add columns including LAG,Lead to get least and recent days from the givens in one row

Tags: sql-server

I have the below two tables :

1. Adjustment Transaction:

[image: Adjustment Transaction]

2. Time Day lookup:

[image: Time Day lookup]

3. The desired output :

[image: the desired output]

My question is can we use LAG & Lead to get the fist/last borrow date in one row same as desired output?

I have figured out the below but it did not work:

```
SELECT     [Mobile Number]

,sum(CASE WHEN Adjustment_Code = 'CRE' then COALESCE ([Adjustment_Amount], 0)else 0 END) as "Total Amount Borrowed",
sum(CASE WHEN Adjustment_Code = 'DEB' then COALESCE(abs([Adjustment_Amount]), 0)else 0  END) as "Total Amount Payback"

,COUNT(CASE WHEN Adjustment_Code = 'CRE' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Total TRX Borrowed]
,COUNT(CASE WHEN Adjustment_Code = 'DEB' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Total TRX Payback]

, (select LEAD(Full_Date, 5, 0) OVER (PARTITION By adjustment_code ORDER BY date_key) AS Lead_2

from [Adjustment Transaction] )


FROM dbo.[Adjustment Transaction] INNER JOIN dbo.[Time Day Lookup] ON dbo.[Adjustment Transaction].Date_Key = dbo.[Time Day Lookup].Date_Key


group by [Mobile Number],Full_Date
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please format your code as code (start lines of code with 4 spaces) this will improve readability and make it easier for users to answer.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question fully. Can you not use MIN(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY MOBILE_NUMBER) AS FIRST_BORROW_DATE, MAX(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY (MOBILE_NUMBER) AS LAST_BORROW_DATE. I feel your requirement is simple but the explanation is not very clear.

Comment: Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, [avoid pictures of code...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584) After reading, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed, though you'll probably figure out the answer once you start formatting your code properly.

Comment: @wahoaml  i have a test , requesting to do the desired output with LAG & LEAD

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this which uses Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation to our advantage.

```
mobilenumber datekey     amount      code
------------ ----------- ----------- ----
1            1           10          cre
1            1           10          cre
1            2           10          cre
1            2           10          deb
1            3           10          deb
1            3           10          cre

(6 row(s) affected)

id          date
----------- -----------------------
1           2017-01-01 00:00:00
2           2017-01-02 00:00:00
3           2017-01-03 00:00:00

(3 row(s) affected)

select t.mobilenumber,
        sum(case when code = 'cre' then amount else 0 end) sumcre,
        sum(case when code = 'deb' then amount else 0 end) sumdeb,
        min(date) mindate,
        max(date) maxdate
from 
    (
    select t.*,d.date from t join dimtime d on d.id = t.datekey and t.code = 'cre'
    union 
    select t.*,null from t join dimtime d on d.id = t.datekey and t.code = 'deb'
        ) t
group by t.mobilenumber

mobilenumber sumcre      sumdeb      mindate                 maxdate
------------ ----------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1            30          20          2017-01-01 00:00:00     2017-01-03 00:00:00
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(1 row(s) affected)
```